# C# referencing another .cs (method to split up code either in either procedural/oo way)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class

I come from a procedural world so bear with me on this. I am not sure of the "proper" terminology. I get functions - classes not so much (I gather they are blue prints but I can't convince myself to use them yet, probably because I do not understand how helpful they can be)

I am attempting to create a C# console application (in VS2010). It acts in a procedural nature (starts from top, may reference a function every once in a while or try catch and then exits). My issue is that there will be say 4 pieces to the application - the portion that defines what the sql strings are, the portion that connects to the database, the portion that executes sql statements and the portion that does extra calculations based on the results.

I'm trying to determine a way of splitting up these chunks of code into different files that I can call from - essentially keeping the default "program.cs" from being too bulky. My code up to date works its just a beating to scroll through to pick out items.

Suggestions?

(I understand this is very subjective)

[addition]

The structure of my code right now looks similar to the following - note, [[[[[ ]]]]] are what I refer to as chunks:

```
        [[[[[
        string sqlQueryFetchCalls = "sql lives here";
        ... and more strings for sql... and more... and more
        ]]]]]

        SqlConnection mssqlConnection = new SqlConnection(params);
        try{
            mssqlConnection.Open();
            System.Console.WriteLine("connection opened");}
        catch (Exception errorVar){
            output.Text = errorVar.ToString();}

        [[[[[
        SqlDataReader results = null;
        SqlCommand exec_sqlQueryFetchCalls = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryFetchCalls, mssqlConnection);
        results = exec_sqlQueryFetchCalls.ExecuteReader();

        while (results.Read())
        {
            // do something
            }results.Close();

        ... again... again ... again... again, though the resulting actions are quite different each time ]]]]]

        mssqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to say anything without some code. Can you please post the relevant code? The method declarations will probably do if they have meaningful names.

Comment: When you say 'portion', think 'class'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't the best way to arrange your code, it can be done.

If you are using `static` methods just make sure that all the methods are in the same namespace. Then they will all be able to see each other.

You can use a single class an use the `partial` keyword to split the definition across several files.

However, I would suggest that you read up more on classes and how they are organised as you will find it a lot easier to manage your code if you use them.

Comment: Also I'd like to add that if you are using Visual Studio as your editor, there is a `#region` keyword that will group parts of your code so you can collapse or expand parts of your code. This is a very useful thing when trying to look for methods lost between lots of code

Comment: Agreed. I am taking the approach of: a, get it to work, b, get it to work cleaner, c, get it to work more oo, d, get to bed

Icemanind, interesting. This will help but it may make me lazy in my approach if I rely on it too often :)

Thanks for the assistance all

Comment: @icemanind - my point of view is that if you feel the need to use regions in the code, the method/class is trying to do to much. Extract methods and classes with single responsibilities instead of "grouping" the code with regions.

Answer (score 0):

Classes usually means "nouns"

Your "portions" sounds like (static?) methods (ie functions).

You might use classes to represent the data that comes from your SQL database. A typical example would be, for instance if you stored data about people in your database, then typically you might have a class called Person. You might have properties in your class, for example Age and Name.

Each row would represent an instance of your class.

Using classes is just an abstraction, using classes brings a whole bunch to the party, but one the most obvious of these, is that it makes it easy to read your code, consider this simple example

```
// Remember Person would be a class you defined somewhere else

// Get a list of people from the database
List<Person> people = GetPeopleFromDatabase();

 // do something to each row in the database .. or person in your List<>
foreach (person in people)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name  + " is " person.Age + " years old");
 }
```

this is a lot easier to understand than

```
    results = exec_sqlQueryFetchCalls.ExecuteReader();

    while (results.Read())
    {
         Console.WriteLine(row[0]  + " is " + row[2] + " years old");
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. I agree, much easier. Bit of an exception in my case since the column headers are thankfully self explanatory (first_name, last_name, etc), however, yours just looks better and does not require the continual use of    results["column_name"].ToString()

Comment: Another nice thing about my version is that Visual Studio's intellisense means I don't have to remember the names of my columns :-)